# Login with Facebook, register new account, still connected to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, registration, facebook-login

Ok so on my website, I'm using Facebook login via the JS SDK.

I have login and registration workflow working well. But one thing I can't wrap my head around is the following workflow:

- User A creates an account on my website, and associates their FB with it.

  - This is either a "Signup with FB" account, or a traditional signup who later links their FB account, doesn't matter.
- User A logs out of my website.
- User B creates a traditional signup on my website **from the same computer**, any FB-related stuff from User A is shown to User B. This is the problem.

I'm presuming my website's `logout` workflow should also call `FB.logout()` but it seems weird to force them out of FB. The docs seem to suggest this, but I feel that should only happen **IF AND ONLY IF** the person **wasn't** logged in to FB from the start, and initiated their FB session through my site. In that case it makes sense for my site to log them out of both.

Regardless, if `FB.logout` is my only option, consider this scenario:

- User A creates account with `userA@example.com`
- User A initiates `FB.login()`, linking the accounts because the FB email is the same
- User A logs out (of my site and FB)
- User B creates an account with `userB@example.com`
- User B initiates `FB.login()` but logs into the same FB account as UserA (let's say this is a husband/wife on same computer or something)
- Now the FB account is associated with two accounts on my site?

Some clarification on how to handle account mergers/conflicts when someone logs into the same FB account on the same computer is what I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody help me out? I'm still running into this and can't find what I'm looking for. I'm happy to re-word my scenario if the above is confusing. Thanks.